# Reshaping data file from rows to columns in SQL-SERVER

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, transpose

I have a query that returns a dataset with 2 columns, as shown below:

```
--------------------------
|spec-number|project    |
|-----------|-----------|
|649841     |A          |
|649841     |B          |
|649841     |D          |
|84709      |E          |
|84709      |B          |
|84709      |C          |
|84709      |K          |
-------------------------
```

The number of projects a spec-number could be involved in could potentially be infinite.

What I would like the result to look like is:

```
-------------------------------------------------
|spec-number|project1|project2|project3|project4|
|-----------|--------|--------|--------|--------|  
|649841     |A       |B       |D       |        | 
|84709      |E       |B       |C       |K       |
-------------------------------------------------
```

I tried pivoting but it just gives me a cross tab of projects by spec-number. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want them as separate columns, then you can calculate the project number and use that for pivoting.  The following uses the `group by` method for aggregation:

```
select spec_num,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then project end) as project1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then project end) as project2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then project end) as project3,
       max(case when seqnum = 4 then project end) as project4
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by spec_number order by project) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by spec_num;
```

If you need a variable number of columns, then you'll have to use dynamic SQL.  This can also be phrased as a `pivot` query, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. Almost there! there could be a variable number of project columns. Could you point me to an example of the dynamic sql code you are talking about?

Comment: Here is an example:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10404348/sql-server-dynamic-pivot-query.